# Deploying a Grails app with Tomcat on an existing site

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, virtualhost, proxypass

I am trying to deploy a grails app on an existing site (mysite.org) using Tomcat with a virtual host, and I've been told I also need to use a ProxyPass and a ProxyPathReverse to the chosen port. I've successfully set up Tomcat, added the WAR file to the tomcat/default-root folder, and edited the server.xml file to include this, an exclusion for serving content to the app.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
ProxyPreserveHost On



ProxyTimeout 3600
Timeout 3600 

ProxyPass /interventions !

ProxyPass / http://00.00.000.000:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://00.00.000.000:8080/

ServerName interventions.mysite.org

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, what I want to happen is to be able to go to interventions.mysite.org and use this app. I know I need to properly configure the virtual host but I've gotten lost in guides that seem to focus on setting it up from the start rather than integrating with an existing site, which had me worried about making any changes without realising (given my lack of knowledge right now).

What should my next step be, and are there any resources I should seek out (or search terms I should use, as I'm totally overwhelmed after my attempts)?

**Edit: Is my wishing to use interventions.mysite.org rather than, say, mysite.org/interventions complicating the issue?

Comment: can you specify the path to the .war file and the name of the .war file you have deployed ? Do you have more than one application deployed on this Tomcat server ? _btw I also lost a lot of time with Grails + Tomcat + Apache HTTPD configs and not all my problems have been properly fixed until now._

Comment: The path is /usr/share/tomcat7-root/default_root/appname and the .war is appname.war. This app is the only one I'm deploying on this server

Comment: try deploying the application with the name ROOT.war

Answer (score 2):

create a site in apache called interventions.mysite.org.conf

To create the site you can just copy the already existing site file found in the sites-available folder in your apache installation and just make edits where necessary.

You file should look like the one i have pasted below, i believe the code i have pasted below should work fine for you, just make edits to the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse fields to match your app installation.

Remember to enable the site by using the command below;

```
sudo a2ensite interventions.mysite.org.conf
```

and also ensure that you have i think mod_proxy enabled.

it can config just like the one below;

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName interventions.mysite.org

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        ProxyErrorOverride      On

        ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:port/my-app/
        ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:port/my-app/
    </VirtualHost>
```

You can also read the apache docs if you don't understand some of the config parameters. Hope that helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! 
I've tried this, and interventions.mysite.org just redirects to mysite.org. Any ideas?

Comment: could you probably share your config and i see?